# django dynamic form value based on foreign key

Tags: django, forms, dynamic

Hope everyone is enjoying the holidays! :)

Can I have a form in django where the default values of all other fields (ForeignKey, CharField, etc) are dependent on the value of a single field i.e. a ForeignKey (value selected in a dropdown field)?

**Here is my scenario:**

- Country = [US, DE, CH, etc] (ForeignKey)
- Language = [English, German, Mandarin, etc] (ForeignKey)
- My to-be form will have fields: Country, Language
- I want the language to automatically change based on the country selected by the user. However, the user should be able to change it to any of the above listed options.

Thank you in advance! Merry Christmas!

Comment: Are you wanting this to happen client-side or server-side?

Comment: If you want to achieve this server-side you can override the save method of your model to fill the language field according to the country when language is None (sorry for the lack of a proper answer but it's hard to write code from my mobile :=)

Comment: If this is to happen server side you need to solve how you want your data to be saved. Fetching it on a condition is less of a problem.

Comment: I am wanting this to happen on the client-side. Can a django feature help me there?

Comment: Also, thank you furins and Rickard for your answers. I really appreciate that. I am stuck with this problem since a long time and unable to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to achieve this on the client side and I'm afraid a django feature would not be able to help you on the client side. You'll need to rely on a client side  languages such as `javascript` and `jQuery`.

I would suggest you to have a look at [jquery-related-selects](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-related-selects) to achieve what you want. On the server side you can use the [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#initial) method to set the initial data of a field and/or also manipulate data by overriding the `__init__()` or `save()` method(s) of a form (if you have passed an instance to the form).

You can do a whole lot with django until the form is rendered, But once the form has been rendered, you'll need to take care of the stuff on `client-side` until you post[pass] the data back to django.

Keep coding, and have a great year ahead !